# How to see that solution of PDE increases with time

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

How do I tell if the solution of $u_t=au_{xx}+bu$ on $[0,1]\times(0,T]$ and $a,b>0$ is increasing in time? $u(x,0)=g(x), u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0$.

Comment: What is domain of $u(x,t)$?

Comment: What are the boundary conditions?

Comment: We know that $\int_{0}^{1}{u_{t}dx} = \int_{0}^{1}{bu + au_{xx}dx} < 0$ if $u$ decreasing at in time at $t$. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: $$u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \alpha_n \sin(n\pi x)e^{(b-n^2\pi^2 a)t}
\quad\text{ where }\quad \alpha_n = 2 \int_0^1 g(x)\sin(n\pi x)dx$$

For large $n$, $u(x,t)$ will be dominated by the smallest $n$
where $\alpha_n$ is non-zero. If $\alpha_n \ne 0$ for any 
$n < \frac{1}{\pi}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}$, then $u(x,t)$ will be increasing in magnitude for large enough $t$.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of your initial/boundary value problem, for a modified heat equation, does not increase in time, but if you analyze the solution as a sum of sines
$$
u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n(t)\,\sin(nx),
$$
then some of the coefficients of the sines could be increasing functions, and that depends on $b$. In fact, it is not hard to see that
$$
u_n(t)=u_n(0)\mathrm{e}^{(b-an^2\pi^2)t},
$$
and hence $u_n$ is increasing iff $b\ge an^2\pi^2$.

Note also that
\begin{align}
0 &=\int_0^1 \big(u_tu-au_{xx}u-bu^2),dx \\ 
&=\int_0^1 \Big(\frac{1}{2}(u^2)_t-a(uu_{x})_x+a(u_x)^2-bu^2\Big)\,dx
\end{align}
and as $\int_0^1 (uu_x)_x\,dx=0$, due to periodicity of $u$, 
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 u^2\,dx =\int_0^1 \big(bu^2-a(u_x)^2\big)\,dx,
$$
where we observe that there are two competing dynamics: the $b$ term, which wants to increase
to $L^2$-norm of $u$ and the $a$ term, which wants to do the opposite.